# Get notified on clipboard change in swift

Tags: swift, clipboard

is there any Clipboard Change Event in swift?
how can i get notified when clipboard changed in iOS application
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can capture UIPastedboardChangedNotification as described in this link:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPasteboard_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/UIPasteboardChangedNotification

Example: (impossible to make the code appeared correctly, I've pasted an image.

1. Add notification to your didFinishLaunchingwithOptions call-back in AppDelegate
2. Add function to handle when UIPastedboardChangedNotification sent to you AppDelegate

[image]

Comment: this code worked in my app but if i copy a text out of app it not worked. please help me

Comment: this may cause memory warning. is there any other option for my question. i want to check when a user copy a text twice.

Comment: up to do ate working link to `UIPasteboardChanged`:  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification.name/1622104-uipasteboardchanged

Comment: Thanks a lot Hoa ;-) Saved me a few headaches!

Answer (score 19):

Here is a copy-able **swift 5.0** version

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(clipboardChanged),
                                               name: UIPasteboard.changedNotification, object: nil)
```

And further, if you want to get the text in your clipboard in this event,

```
    @objc func clipboardChanged(){
        let pasteboardString: String? = UIPasteboard.general.string
        if let theString = pasteboardString {
            print("String is \(theString)")
            // Do cool things with the string
        }
    }
```

Comment: It should be noted that this is **iOS only**. MacOS does not seem to have an equivalent notification, all the soltions I found are timer-based.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    // ...

    // Clipboard
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(internalClipboardChanged), name: UIPasteboard.changedNotification, object: nil)

    // ...
}

func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
    // ...
    self.clipboardChanged()
}

// CLIPBOARD
@objc func internalClipboardChanged() {
    // ...
    self.clipboardChanged()
}

func clipboardChanged() {
    if (UIPasteboard.general.hasImages) {
        self.controller!.clipboardImage = UIPasteboard.general.image
    } else {
        self.controller!.clipboardImage = nil
    }
}
```