# How can I get selected text from ImageAnalysisInteraction on UIImageView?

Tags: ios, visionkit, ios16

I work on an iOS app that displays images that often contain text, and I'm adding support for `ImageAnalysisInteraction` as described in [this WWDC 2022 session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10026/). I have gotten as far as making the interaction show up and being able to select text and get the system selection menu, and even add my own action to the menu via the [`buildMenuWithBuilder` API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/3327317-buildmenuwithbuilder). But what I really want to do with my custom action is get the selected text and do a custom lookup-like thing to check the text against other content in my app.

So how do I get the selected text from an `ImageAnalysisInteraction` on a `UIImageView`? The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/visionkit/imageanalysisinteraction) show methods to check if there *is* selected text, but I want to know *what the text is*.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to solve the same problem. However, there doesn't currently seem to be any straightforward way to get selected text from `ImageAnalysisInteraction`. The closest thing seems to be the `ImageAnalysis.transcript` property, but it contains all the OCR text, not just what the user selected.

My solution was to capture the text whenever the user taps on the copy button on the selection menu. You can do this by observing clipboard changes, which allows you to copy the selected text from the clipboard whenever a change is detected.

See:

- [Get notified on clipboard change in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29516503/get-notified-on-clipboard-change-in-swift)
- [How to copy text to clipboard/pasteboard with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24670290/how-to-copy-text-to-clipboard-pasteboard-with-swift)

Comment: it was added at wwdc23

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help you

```
// Step -1
import Vision
// Step -2
// converting image into CGImage
guard let cgImage = imageWithText.image?.cgImage else {return}
// Step -3
// creating request with cgImage
let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: cgImage, options: [:])
// Step -4
let request = VNRecognizeTextRequest { request, error in
     guard let observations = request.results as [VNRecognizedTextObservation],
     error == nil else {return}
     let text = observations.compactMap({
     $0.topCandidates(1).first?.string
     }).joined(separator: ", ")
     print(text) // text we get from image
}
   // step -5
    request.recognitionLevel = VNRequestTextRecognitionLevel
    try handler.perform([request])
```

[For Reference and more details](https://medium.com/ivymobility-developers/text-recognition-from-image-in-swift-3dd33714b4ba)

Comment: I found this. Article also https://betterprogramming.pub/enabling-live-text-interactions-with-images-in-swiftui-5dd1d7f1676

Comment: What I really want is the text that the user has selected, though. I'd rather not have to re-do the whole image analysis. And if I did this, I'd have to get the coordinates of the selected text somehow and then check for text results at those coordinates.

Comment: It now exists .